# Microsoft translator API , Translate.execute() method not invokes in android

Tags: java, android, api, microsoft-translator

I am trying to make an Android app that will use some API for translation (now I use Microsoft API - microsoft-translator-java-api-0.6.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar )

I have done this for single String, but I want to translate some pdf file. Someone know how can I send PDF to this translator and get it back translated?

```
public class FirstFrag extends MainNavigation.SectionFrag {

private Button translate;

String translatedText;

public FirstFrag(){
    super();
}
public static FirstFrag newInstance(Context c, int section){
    FirstFrag ret = new FirstFrag();
    ret.setSection(section);
    return ret;
}

@Override
public void afterCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.afterCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.first_frag_layout);

    translate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnProgressBar);
    translate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            translate.setEnabled(false);
                new TranslateFromBing().execute();

        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onRetryClicked() {}

// Async Task Class
class TranslateFromBing extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {

    Translate.setClientId("MY CLIENT ID");
    Translate.setClientSecret("MY CLIENT SECRET");

    translatedText = null;
    try {
        translatedText = Translate.execute("Bonjour le monde", Language.FRENCH, Language.ENGLISH);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

        return null;
    }


    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Translation complete", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        TextView translated = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.translatedText);
        if(translatedText != null) {
            translated.setText(translatedText);
        }
        else {
            translated.setText("ERROR HERE");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are invoking `execute` inside method that is called on UI thread. I dont know this API but it most probably does communicate with server and if it returns data immediately - and not through some kind of callback, then it is probably doing HTTP communication.

This is not allowed under android, you should call this api inside AsyncTask.

Another thing is, You should analyze logcat - it should provide you with additional hints on whats wrong. The fact you call `execute` inside try/catch is probably because you were getting `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`.